# How to use android as ANCS content provider?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ancs

I'm trying to demo android side service (content provider in ANCS lingo), that communicates with embedded device that supports Apple Notification Service (ANCS) notification consumer. Reason for this is, that the embedded device only supports ANCS. As the ANCS BLE side things are publiced by Apple, this should be possible and I've already added that service + associated characterics to android side gatt server. Embedded device is nordic nRF52 and SW is nordic ANCS demo. Demo works OK with iPhone and apparently with the desktop version of nRF control panel (if added with nordic supplied config and if you have windows machine, which I don't).

However I cannot seem to be able to bond the device with android, that's required before connection. The advertisement is in limited discovery mode (before bonding) so I cannot find it via regular scanning from settings. Also bonding from java code doesn't work. With mBluetoothDevice.createBond() I get  ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED callback with state 10 (BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) with old state 11(BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING). Apparently I would need to exchange keys here, but no idea how to do that.

Also dunno if anyone has done this same exercise before, but any other tips would also be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have detailed info how the whole initial ANCS communication should go. Does the content provider initate the communication? Via gatt server (gattserver.connect) or via gatt client (bluetoothdevice.connectGatt). Also does the Content Provider read or write something to Content Consumer solicitated service?

The apple developer document doens't even mention the CCCD:s for the characteristics. So anything more detailed would be nice.

Comment: Hey I want to use ANCS on android but I have some help.I advertise data in GATT server on android device but BLE device not subscribe.Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the phone BLE stack was corrupted or in some invalid state. REboot and removing battery solved the issue with the bonding.